# MongoDB combine three collections and get results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What I'm trying to achieve is to get alliance members and then I need to get alliance members stats from users table. This is my code so far:

```
Alliance.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "alliancemembers",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "ally_id",
            "as": "allymembers"
        },
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "allymembers",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "members"
        }            
    }
```

So in first lookup I get a members who are in alliance and the problem is that I don't know how to write second lookup to use allymembers from first lookup and aggregate with User (users collection)

```
Alliance:  _id title
alliancemembers (collection from DB):  _id  ally_id user_id
User: _id username current_exp level arena_wins arena_losses
```

Now I need to do leaderboard of alliances and sort the alliances by alliance members stats
as you can see alliance members stats are held in users collection(edited)
and IDK how to combine all three of them

Everything is done with MongoDB mongoose

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet What schema do you exactly need ?

Comment: "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.0",